# Trying to access applicationContext to save SharedPreferences returns kotlinnullpointerexception

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, instance

I need to access applicationContext in order to save and retrieve sharedpreferences

```
class MainApplication : Application() {

    init {
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        private var instance: MainApplication? = null

        fun applicationContext() : Context {
            return instance!!.applicationContext
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val context: Context = applicationContext()

    }
}
```

Then I have an Object class that will need this context to access the sharedpreferences

```
object SharedPrefsUtils {

    fun retrieveRefreshToken():String?{
        val sharedPreference = MainApplication.applicationContext().applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("USER_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        return sharedPreference.getString("refresh_token","NO_TOKEN")
    }
}
```

But this is giving me that the applicationContext is null with

```
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.MainApplication$Companion.applicationContext(MainApplication.kt:17)
```

Comment: why dont you just pass in the context instead of trying to get context through a static method? Its very easy to create memory leaks doing it that way

Comment: because I need to access this context from an non UI thread

Comment: how can I make it work @tyczj ?

Comment: so pass it in/down to where it needs to go, you saying that it need to access it from a different thread makes my statement of causing memory leaks even more of a concern. Better yet pass in the refresh token to the background thread before you start the work then you dont have to worry about it at all

Comment: So it turns out that I forgot to declare this application in manifest